# Data provider for REST API

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, ado.net

My application works directly with Oracle data base, using standard ADO objects DbConnection, DbDataReader, DbDataAdapter and so on.

Now I have a task to get the same data from REST web service (http commands: get, post, put).
In my opinion, the best way to complete this task is to create a data provider for this web service, implementing ADO objects.
In my application all code works only with base ADO objects. I can provide new command text for data base commands.

I don't have an experience with classes, which provide functionality to work with http in .Net Framework. I don't know where to start.

What is the best way to complete this task? 
What types may I use from .NET Framework? Maybe there are some implementations of similar tasks?

Answer (score 0):

There is something that fits perfectly your needs Odata(WCF data Service ) which will publish a REST API to access your data, Check out this article for more information

[WCF DATA services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728286(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: As I understand, OData is a protocol that uses a Rest architecture. So to use WCF Data Service web server should implement OData. But my server doesn't implemet it. This is an existing web server that provides an information through http. I should write only client application.

Comment: That is not what odata is.
It's just gonna implement the functionalities that you may take some time to implement with a regulat REST WCF here is a video explaining a simple tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m51wIoMk2XM

Answer (score 0):

To realise a simple provider I've decided to use Web API 2.
I.e. `DbConnection` represents a wrapper for `HttpClient`, `DbCommand` - wrapper for `HttpRequestMessage`.

Other ADO objects will have it's own representation based on these objects.

I'd also suggest to read this book [Designing Evolvable Web APIs with ASP.NET](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/index.html)

Comment: Can you post an example of `DbConnection` and `DbCommand` wrappers?